# How to develop web ui with Google App Engine Java platform

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web

I have started learning Google App Engine Java. Although, I guess Java is good for server side coding, its just not efficient to code for web in Java. Is there any framework or language that I can use to write code for Web front end in Google App Engine, Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you learn Java, the most logical choice for a client UI is GWT:

[GWT Overview](http://www.gwtproject.org/overview.html)

GWT is a toolkit that takes your Java code and translates the client portion of it into a highly optimized JavaScript that works across all major browsers. It makes it easy to create very complex rich client applications using a combination of Java code, GWT widgets, as well as regular HTML and CSS.

Comment: Looks like a daunting task. Learning GWT! Thanks!